# Python: How to switch of outer axes in 3D subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot two 3D plots side by side. However my result looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to remove the outer axes (the ones going from [0..1])

Everything I tried so far

```
ax.axis('off')
```

and

```
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_zticks([])
```

only removed inner axes (those of the 3D coordinate system), which I want to keep.

Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Generate coordinates for scatter plot
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(data1.shape[0]), np.arange(data1.shape[1]), np.arange(data1.shape[2]))
[x, y, z] = (np.reshape(x, (-1)), np.reshape(y, (-1)), np.reshape(z, (-1)))

# Generate scatter plot
numRows = 1
numCols = 2
fig, axes = plt.subplots(numRows, numCols, figsize=(20, 12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
scat = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=np.reshape(data1, (-1)), cmap='jet', marker="s")
ax = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
scat = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=np.reshape(data2, (-1)), cmap='jet', marker="s")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating two sets of subplots. One by using

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(...)
```

and the other by doing

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
```

They pretty much do the same thing, which is why you are seeing two sets of axes. You don't need to create the two subplots when you are creating the figure. Instead do:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 12))
```

Full example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 5))

ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
ax = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')

plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem!

Comment: Your welcome. If this answered your question, don't forget to accept it to mark the question as solved.